# How do I upload my node.js web app to openshift? It is NOT on git, but just on my computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, deployment, openshift

Ok so locally I have saved a lot of files in a folder, and this web app is just on my computer. It is not on github and I don't want to upload it to github (I don't want it open sourced). So it's just in folders on my computer, and when I run it I open command prompt, go to the folder it's in, and go node server.js. 
So, how in the world do I upload all those needed files into openshift hosting so that this web app can finally be online? All they are talking about is doing it via the command prompt, but I mean it is so many files, like all the little images, and all that. Do I really have to type it all manually somehow in the command? Isn't there an easier way to just click "Upload" somewhere and just select the files I need, kind of like uploading images to photobucket or facebook?

I am a beginner at this, I've never uploaded a web app.

Comment: you need to create a local git repository. code that's "just in folders" is not a program.

Answer (score 0):

Git is not Github.
Github is onlice public service and **git** is just a protocol.

You need to create **local** git repository on your **local** git server and commit your files to it.
[There is a simple guide about doing it for openshift.](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html#)